# Excel 2016 - Merged Cells showing Defined name in background

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I'm a VBA programmer and using Excel 2016, I've created a sheet for a client using merged cells, and named them (defined name).

The problem is that the merged cells have their name as a type of watermark behind the text in the cells (like the "Page 1" etc. in page break view). When printed this does not appear.

I've already tried changing the page view to "Page Break" and this does prevent the names of the cells showing, but I get "Page 1" appearing on the sheet instead. I've also unmerged the cell and this fixed the issue, although this is not the solution I need. I have far too many merged cells (client design) to be able to do this and keep the layout the same.

I just need to have the sheet appear without the merged cell name in the background.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have managed to get around this is by using some code to remove the defined names in the workbook

```
                NewWB = "MyNewWorkbook.xlsx"
                Workbooks(NewWB).Activate

                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                    For i = Workbooks(NewWB).Names.Count To 1 Step -1
                        Workbooks(NewWB).Names(i).Delete
                    Next
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Hope this helps anyone in future with the same issue.